# Fermionic contribution to central charge in $\mathcal{N}=2$ Super Yang-Mills?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, yang-mills

I am trying to replicate the calculation of the central charge for $\mathcal{N}=2$ Super Yang-Mills, by following Weinberg's textbook in section 27.9. He calculates it by finding how one supercurrent transforms under the other supersymmetry transformation.

When he calculates this quantity, he ignores various terms which are bilinear in the fermion fields. He says that these terms "do not concern us here because we are interested in effects of long range boson fields."

What does this mean? Can we simply throw away these terms? I have been trying to simplify all of the terms to somehow write them as a total derivative but I have been unable to do so.